# Count Excel Cells Based on Two Colums and Date being specific day of week

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been googling to try to figure out how to count the number of cells based on multiple conditions of exact text as well as checking the date column to ensure the day of week is a specifc day. I have attached an example of the book. Some Date fields may be blank and should not be counted in any cell.

Pretty much I am trying to combine these two formulas:

If Sales Guy was Bob & Department Was Install & Date Was Not Saturday

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY($C2:C$500)=2,3,4,5,6)) - I know this is not correct, cant figure out how to do multiple days.

=COUNTIFS(A2:A500,"BOB", $B2:$B500,"Install")


column A = Sales Guy

column B = Type (Install or General)

column C = Date Time in this format 6/20/2022 9:56:47 AM
```

Excel Example:

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzZ5r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without an additional column in the source data, you won't be able to use `COUNTIFS`.

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(A2:A500="BOB"),N(B2:B500="Install"),N(TEXT(C2:C500,"ddd")<>"Sat"))`

is one alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add on column to get the weekday.

In my sample, the formula is `=WEEKDAY(C2,2)`.

Then you can get the count with multiple coditions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]